# converting a sub query into self join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, self-join

I have this query in which i want to find who are all the other authors are for each title in which the author is Mr.X

The query I wrote for that is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (author_name) as AUTHORS 
    from table1 
    where title = (Select title from table1 where (author_name) = 'X');
```

I got the ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I think to avoid this error i should use a self join but I'm not able to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your subquery returning more than 1 record and in such case you can't use `=` operator rather You should use `IN` operator to check against multiple values like below

```
where title in (Select title from table1 where (author_name) = 'X')
```

So, your query should look like

```
SELECT DISTINCT (author_name) as AUTHORS 
    from table1 
    where title in (Select title from table1 where (author_name) = 'X');
```

To change it to join instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT (t1.author_name) as AUTHORS 
    from table1 t1
    join table1 t2
    on t1.title = t2.title
```

Answer (score 0):

An extra answer, in my opinion the performance of your query improves using: "count"

```
SELECT DISTINCT (author_name) as AUTHORS 
from table1 t1
where ISNULL((Select COUNT(t2.title) from table1 t2 where (author_name) = 'X' AND t1.title = t2.title), 0) > 0
```

Comment: In a case when I need to "play" with a lot of data I prefer to use a "count" in a subquery.